# D3 Force Nodes Clustering at Top Left

Tags: d3.js

https://jsfiddle.net/abalasky/b28mxfL6/7/

```
function update() {
    //Add Nodes
    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)

    updateNodes();

    simulation.on("tick", ticked);


    //Add links
    simulation.force('link').links(graph.links)

    updateLinks();
}
```

Link to fiddle above. Was following along with this great D3 guide https://tomroth.com.au/fdg-minimal/. Was able to have my force graph up quickly but now that i am trying to repackage everything in functions all my nodes are clustering at the top. I've tried to move around where i call .on('tick') but have been banging my head against the wall with this for hours. Any guidance would beg greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of `node` and `link` variables:

In the original code, these contain the enter selection, e.g.

```
//draw circles for the nodes 
var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "red");
```

In the jsfiddle code, the selection itself is assigned to the variable:

```
node = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
```

This causes `tick` not to have anything on what to iterate.

Here is a corrected version of the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cb9t7fjo/

#### how to identify the cause of this type of problems

`console.log` is your friend in situations like this:

- `console.log('tick', node)` inside the tick function shows that the tick function is executed as expected.
- `console.log(d.x)` inside `node.attr('x')` shows you that this is never executed.

This helps identify that the problem is with `node` (and respectively `link`) variables.